# TMetropolisUIListBoxItem doesn't show Bitmap

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I need to show Bitmap in TMetropolisUIListBoxItem, I've loaded the Bitmap in ItemData.Bitmap still it doesn't show the bitmap.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yep, before asking the question, read all the documentations.

Answer (score 0):

To display bitmap you need to apply style that supports displaying bitmaps, for example you can load Air style from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\Redist\styles\Fmx\Air.Style` and set list box item `StyleLookup` property to `listboxitemleftdetail`

Comment: It only shows a small icon, I want the ListBox full of that bitmap like the startmenu

Comment: @zeref You can try to use `Icon` property instead it fills background of the item